# Story where aliens visit earth in a cucumber spaceship

Tags: story-identification, short-film

I remember watching a film on TV in roughly 1989. It would have been a German production broadcasted on Austrian ORF, or any production but in german synchronized version.

It was in color, not subtitled, depicting a contemporary earth society and environment. Not sure about the length, say one hour. Not a serial.

The story revolves around a pickle-sized cucumber interstellar spaceship (no, not with a rat rib cage exoskeleton) with humanoid crew of at least one female and one male. They could make sections of the cucumber skin translucent for windows. They were explorers, and made contact with what I believe to remember, human children; in the end they got themselves in a position where they were in danger and had to lam to their homeworld. The homeworld was a sentient tree in space, with white dendrites, quite like those on Pandora. There was a philosophical backstory and a morale, of which I remember nothing concrete.

What is the name of that movie, and if it is based on a novel or short story, which?

Comment: I suspect that you're looking for The Galactic Garden - https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/80043/ultra-obscure-bbc-tv-programme-about-microscopic-spacemen/80052#80052

Comment: Did somebody say "A flying pickle!!!"? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5i2aDAoLhsc

Comment: YES YES splendid @andrewsi you're amazing. this stack is amazing. you made my day. feel free to close this or make it a signpost dupe; the other question's title was not showing in the list of potential matches when I drafted this.

Comment: @dlatikay - I saw it when it was initially aired, and for *years* I thought I'd imagined it. When I saw the original question, I did some research and discovered that it was an actual show...

Comment: I was a small child and suspected it must have been a daydream ever since. One of the most elusive shows ever - all links I could find are long dead. An IMDb entry, Vector, Plasmid, and Chimaera. 1985, 100 min. It must actually be real. I'm so intrigued now that I'd pay Bristol a visit to get a copy :)